# Sort an associative array by group with random group ordering

Tags: php, sorting, shuffle

I have an associative array key/values indicating a group. I'd like to shuffle the array so that the groups are in a random order but so that the items in the groups are shuffled only within their group. In other words, I want to take something like this:

```
[
    [
        "name" => "Buffy",
        "group" => 1
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Willow",
        "group" => 1
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Xander",
        "group" => 2
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Giles",
        "group" => 2
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Tara",
        "group" => 3
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Angel",
        "group" => 3
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Spike",
        "group" => 3
    ]
]
```

And return something a bit more like this:

```
[
    [
        "name" => "Spike",
        "group" => 3
    ]
    [
        "name" => "Angel",
        "group" => 3
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Tara",
        "group" => 3
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Willow",
        "group" => 1
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Buffy",
        "group" => 1
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Xander",
        "group" => 2
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Giles",
        "group" => 2
    ],
]
```

I realise this is probably possible with two or three sorts, but it would be great if this could be done with a single `usort`.

Comment: It is an interesting problem, but may I ask, why do you have the initial structure in the example? If you want to do things with groups, why not have:

    [
        "group" => 1,
        "names" => [
            "Buffy",
            "Willow"
        ]
    ]

Answer (score 1):

Basically, my solution shuffles the input array, temporarily restructures the input array to gather subarrays with the same `group` value, then returns the data to its original structure.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7ea33d2015d034158d886eae4908dc6a4817ad0a))

```
shuffle($data);                         // randomize all subarrays
foreach ($data as $set) {
    $grouped[$set['group']][] = $set;   // merge subarrays on group value
}
$output = [];
foreach($grouped as $group) {
    array_push($output, ...$group);     // return to original array structure
}
var_export($output);
```

*Note that `...` (splat operator) allows `array_push()` to store all subarrays (within each group) individually to generate the original structure.

Possible Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Xander',
    'group' => 2,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Giles',
    'group' => 2,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Willow',
    'group' => 1,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Buffy',
    'group' => 1,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Spike',
    'group' => 3,
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Tara',
    'group' => 3,
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Angel',
    'group' => 3,
  ),
)
```

Comment: Is this data, by chance, coming from a queried resultset?

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
$groups = [];
foreach (array_unique(array_column($myar, 'group')) as $k) $groups[$k] = rand();
foreach (array_keys($myar) as $k) $myar[$k]['rnd'] = rand();
usort($myar, function($a, $b) use ($groups) {
    if ($gdif = $groups[$b['group']] - $groups[$a['group']]) return $gdif;
    return $b['rnd'] - $a['rnd'];
    });
foreach (array_keys($myar) as $k) unset($myar[$k]['rnd']);

print_r($myar);
```

Run with your data, this is one result...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Buffy
            [group] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Willow
            [group] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Angel
            [group] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Tara
            [group] => 3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Spike
            [group] => 3
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => Giles
            [group] => 2
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [name] => Xander
            [group] => 2
        )

)
```

Comment: This code doesn't also randomise the order of the groups.

Comment: @Nick.  Thanks.  Missed that.  Give me a few minutes and will fix that and some other bits.